# Java gdxlib flickers when changing dialogs

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rendering, flicker

Hello I have problems with flickering texture in libGdx. I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find a solution.

The texture only flickers when I'm change dialogs with the show (Stage stage) method. There are basically 2 render calls. One from the render where I draw the texture and the second is the draw method in Stage class.

The first one shouldn't flicker when I'm changing dialogs. This is very annoying and I don't know how to solve this.

The app class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Dialog;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window.WindowStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Scaling;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScalingViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class FlickerGame implements ApplicationListener {                                 

    private SpriteBatch batch;                                                            
    private StretchViewport viewport;                                                     
    private HUD hud;                                                                      
    private Texture texture;                                                              
    private BitmapFont font;                                                              

    @Override                                                                             
    public void create() {                                                                

        // use only one SpriteBatch in game                                           
        batch = new SpriteBatch();                                                        
        viewport = new StretchViewport( Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );
        texture = new Texture( Gdx.files.local( "badlogic.jpg" ) );                       
        font = new BitmapFont();                                                          
        hud = new HUD( batch, getSkin() );                                                

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( hud );                                               
    }                                                                                     

    @Override                                                                             
    public void dispose() {                                                               

        batch.dispose();                                                                  
        hud.dispose();                                                                    
        texture.dispose();                                                                
        font.dispose();                                                                   
    }                                                                                     

    @Override                                                                             
    public void resize( int width, int height ) {                                         

        viewport.update( width, height, true );                                           
        hud.getViewport().update( width, height, true );                                  
    }                                                                                     

    @Override                                                                             
    public void render() {                                                                

        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();                                        

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );                                                
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );                                       

        // draw the texture on the whole screen                                           
        batch.setProjectionMatrix( viewport.getCamera().combined );                       
        batch.begin();                                                                    
        batch.draw( texture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );   
        batch.end();                                                                      

        hud.act( delta );                                                                 
        hud.draw();                                                                       
    }                                                                                     

    @Override public void pause() {}                                                      
    @Override public void resume() {}                                                     

    private Skin getSkin(){                                                               

        Skin skin = new Skin();                                                           

        // just add a part of the badlogic.jpg as button looks awful its just for testing 
        Drawable up = new TextureRegionDrawable( new TextureRegion( texture, 0, 0, 50, 8 ) );

        skin.add( DEFAULT, new WindowStyle( font, Color.WHITE, null ), WindowStyle.class );
        skin.add( DEFAULT, new LabelStyle( font, Color.WHITE ), LabelStyle.class );       
        skin.add( DEFAULT, new TextButtonStyle( up, null, null, font ), TextButtonStyle.class );

        return skin;                                                                      
    }                                                                                     

    private static final String DEFAULT = "default";                                      
}
```

The HUD class where I implemented the Dialog.

```
class HUD extends Stage {                                                                 

    private Dialog menu;                                                                  
    private Dialog about;                                                                 
    private Dialog exit;                                                                  

    public HUD( SpriteBatch batch, Skin skin ){                                           

        super( new ScalingViewport( Scaling.stretch, 0.3f * Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0.3f * Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new OrthographicCamera() ), batch );

        final Stage stage = this;                                                         

        menu = new Dialog( "menu", skin ){                                                

            @Override                                                                     
            public void result( Object object ){                                          

                if ( object instanceof Integer ){                                         
                    switch ( (Integer) object ){                                          
                        case 0:                                                           
                            // play button doesn't do anything at the moment              
                            Gdx.app.log( "Button", "play" );                              
                            break;                                                        
                        case 1: about.show( stage ); break;                               
                        case 2: exit.show( stage ); break;                                
                    }                                                                     
                }                                                                         
            }                                                                             
        };                                                                                
        Table menuButtons = menu.getButtonTable();                                        
        menu.button( "play", 0 );                                                         
        menuButtons.row();                                                                
        menu.button( "credits", 1 );                                                      
        menuButtons.row();                                                                
        menu.button( "exit", 2 );                                                         

        about = new Dialog( "credits", skin ){                                            

            @Override                                                                     
            public void result( Object object ){                                          

                menu.show( stage );                                                       
            }                                                                             
        };                                                                                
        about.text( "made by me!" );                                                      
        about.button( "back" );                                                           

        exit = new Dialog( "", skin ){                                                    

            @Override                                                                     
            public void result( Object object ){                                          

                if ( object instanceof Boolean ){                                         
                    if ( (Boolean) object ){                                              
                        Gdx.app.exit();                                                   
                    } else {                                                              
                        menu.show( stage );                                               
                    }                                                                     
                }                                                                         
            }                                                                             
        };                                                                                
        exit.text( "Are you sure you want to exit?" );                                    
        exit.button( "yes", true );                                                       
        exit.button( "no", false );                                                       

        menu.show( this );                                                                
    }                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints to see where you call the render/show method and actually draw your image.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? Is it the addAction method with the stage.getActionsRequestRendering() and Gdx.graphics.requestRendering() that is causing the flickering.

Comment: What's this line `final Stage stage = this;` ? You never seem to use it.
**edit**: your code has blatant compilation flaws, such as missing parenthesis. Could you double-check you didn't do an error pasting?

Comment: With copy/paste some lines got cut off. The code should compile now.

Comment: I thought so. And for the `final Stage stage = this;`? Why do you do that and `about.show( stage )` instead of passing `this` directly? Are you duplicating the stages?

Comment: I use the 'final Stage stage = this'  to save the reference. Its because im overriding the 'result( Object object );' i cant use this in that method body. There are no duplicates of the stages.

Comment: @Nathan Did you try to run the code and could you confirm the bug?

Comment: No. I can't at my work (I have to modify the entire badlogic configuration, as we don't have direct access to the libs), and I forgot at home. I'll look it up this night or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

For closure the solution was just to create a new SpriteBatch in the HUD class like this:

```
super( new ScalingViewport(
    Scaling.stretch,
    0.3f * Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
    0.3f * Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
    new OrthographicCamera() ),
    new SpriteBatch()
);
```

The flickering didn't happen at all. The wiki explained that "A SpriteBatch is a pretty heavy object so you should only ever have one in your program." so this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the color of the SpriteBatch is changed. Drawing code doesn't try to keep the color whatever it was previously because that would require a lot of unnecessary color changes. Set it to white before drawing the background or anything else.